# Did the Gang of Four thoroughly explore "Pattern Space"?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

Ever since I first learned about the [Gang of Four (GoF) design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), at least 10 years ago, I am having the impression that these 23 patterns should be only a small sample of something much larger which I like to call the *Pattern Space*. This hypothetical *Pattern Space* consists of all recommendable solutions (known or unknown) for common object oriented software design problems.

So I expected the number of known and documented design patterns to grow significantly.

It did not happen. More than 20 years after the GoF book came out, only 12 additional patterns are listed in the Wikipedia article, most of which are much less popular than the original ones. (I did not include the concurrency patterns here because they cover a specific topic.)

What are the reasons?

- Is the GoF set of patterns actually more comprehensive than I think?
- Did the interest in finding new patterns drop, maybe because they have been found to not be all that useful in software design?
- Something else?

Comment: Patterns are everywhere but they're often used in a tasteless and robotic way. For that reason, I think, the pattern catalogue idea became less popular.

Comment: Here are some cloud patterns in case you're interested: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600223.aspx. There are lots of special purpose patterns like this in programming. It's rare to have them catalogued. Sometimes, it's called a set of best practices.

Comment: Design space? Someone get Mark Rosewater down here, stat!

Comment: Martin Fowler published [*Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*](https://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420) in 2003 documenting about 50 patterns, many of which are still quite reconizable and well-used today, e.g. "Data Mapper", "Plugin", "Lazy Load", "Service Layer", etc.

Comment: @BrianRogers: Yes, but these are not patterns for generaral object oriented design and thus not an extension of the GoF patterns. The pattern concept, originating from architecture, has been applied to a number of fields like requirements, software architecture, UI design and management, but that's a different story.

Comment: Exploring the space of all possible patterns would be like not exploring the space of possible patterns at all. You can make everything a pattern. If you make everything a pattern then nothing is a pattern, as the word loses it's meaning.

Comment: This question has to be primarily opinion based. Just the very *definition* of a pattern is controversial, very subjective... let alone the remainder of the question that is built on top of it. I think this question, as it stands is pretty much unanswerable in any way that will be useful to many readers.

Comment: @BradThomas: Sure, like with most interesting questions, people tend to have a certain opinion. But opinions are at least partly based on facts, and I have found many intersesting facts in the answers to this question that will help myself and hopefully others to re-think their opinions and come to more substantiated ones.

Comment: Patterns are codified experience. Experience is that which allows you to recognize a mistake when you've made it again.

Comment: @keshlam: This mostly applies to the concept of anti-patterns. And actually I believe that anti-patterns are often more helpful than patterns. Another advantage is that they don't require you to copy/paste code around :).

Answer (score 172, accepted):

When the Book came out, a lot of people thought that way, and there were many efforts to create "pattern libraries" or even "pattern communities." You can still find some of them:

- ["Pattern Community"](http://wiki.c2.com/?PatternCommunity), *WikiWikiWeb*
- ["The Design Patterns Study Group of New York City"](https://www.industriallogic.com/patterns/), *Industrial Logic*
- ["Patterns Catalog"](http://www.hillside.net/patterns/patterns-catalog), *The Hillside Group*

But then...

> Did the interest in finding new patterns drop, maybe because they are not really that useful in software design?

This, very much. The point of design patterns is improve *communication* between developers, but if you try to add more patterns you quickly get to the point where people can't remember them, or misremember them, or disagree on what exactly they should look like, and communication is not, in fact, improved. That already happens a lot with the GoF patterns.

Personally, I'd go even further:  Software design, especially good software design, is far too varied to be meaningfully captured in patterns, especially in the small number of patterns people can actually remember – and they’re far too abstract for people to really remember more than a handful. So they’re not helping much.

And far too many people become enamoured with the concept and try to apply patterns everywhere – usually, in the resulting code you can’t find the actual design between all the (completely meaningless) Singletons and Abstract Factories.

Comment: Controversial opinion:  The abstract factory is a code smell anyway :)

Comment: In the age of languages that allow `invokeConstructor((object[])args)` ... rigidity is completely meaningless.

Comment: Controversial opinion, maybe, but an oh so important opinion to express. Design patterns are in danger of becoming an example of the emperor's new clothes, where we are all scared to question whether they are useful. Well done.

Comment: @MetaFight Where can I read more? I use dependency injected factories quite often and would like to know if im making a mistake.

Comment: @MetaFight, everyone is entitled to an opinion, but without argumentation, it seems quite substanceless. Could you give your reasons why you believe the abstract factory is a code smell?

Comment: @Gusdor I'm not against Factories.  It's *abstract* Factories that I worry about.  I have never found an instance in the wild where an Abstract Factory wasn't hiding a deep architectural or modelling mistake.

Comment: @MetaFight `ControversialDesignPatternOnlineOpinionHumanReadableRetortFactory.newInstance().getText();`

Comment: "*The point of design patterns is improve communication between developers*" I thought design patterns were to solve problems that were commonly (and quite often independently) encountered by developers. Standards improve communication, and due to fluctuations (patterns arising from XY problems, patterns being considered anti-patterns) many don't consider design patterns to be standards. Design patterns are good at pin-pointing lack of language features, and I believe language designers are implementing these problem-fixes before they become design patterns. Don't take my word for fact though

Comment: I didn't find patterns useful for documenting the architecture of *my* software, for my peers/team (except a very few of the simplest e.g. "Singleton"). I *did* find them useful to learn, from experts, without reading their code, what can be done to structure software... e.g. I had recently learned an OO languages (C++) and learned that I could write "classes" and virtual or pure virtual methods ... what else could I do with the language? Reading _Design Patterns_ (the GoF book, and to a lesser extend the PLoP books) helped me understand why it's worth knowing an OO programming language.

Comment: @ChrisW The GoF design patterns were meant to overcome the OO progamming languages shortcomings, so while it is true that reading it could help you writing OO code, you could have avoided the shortcomings at all by learning a functional language (or more dynamic OO languages) instead.

Comment: @Shautieh At the time (1995), the Microsoft compiler was C or C++.

Comment: @ChrisW I don't see your point... As I said the GoF tried to overcome OO shortcomings, and especially C++98 shortcomings as this was their language of choice along with Smalltalk. They actually wrote : "The choice of programming language is important because it influences one's point of view. Our patterns assume Smalltalk/C++-level language features, and that choice determines what can and cannot be implemented easily."

Comment: @Shautieh I thought you were telling me that I could have avoided the need for GoF patterns by using a functional language; my reply was that they were useful at the time, when C++ was the main choice or only choice for certain kinds of software.

Comment: @MetaFight How are you unit testing those factories? I get twitchy if i can't mock the objects I inject. Especially implementations of web service endpoints or databases.

Comment: @Gusdor you inherits them and override their method ? of course if they can't be overrided you're screwed :P

Comment: @VinceEmigh I agree with you, it's UML that was designed to improve communication between developers but also with some non devlopers for the highest order diagram (use case,sequential,..).

Comment: It's also worth noting that not all languages are object-oriented, and many patterns don't apply outside of the OO space. We've seen trends towards different programming paradigms with their own patterns.

Comment: The idea that you have a buffet of "code structures" that you can choose and add to your project is the fruit of a deep misunderstanding of what design patterns are and sheer lazyness. The GoF didn't try to _solve_ anything with that book on patterns, they were just documenting what was commonly used.

Comment: @Shautieh _"GoF tried to overcome OO shortcomings, and especially C++98 shortcomings"_ ... small chronological point: GoF was early 90's (published 1994); C++98 was late 90's. Not that C++ changed hugely in that time with respect to support for the kinds of structures that GoF were drawing attention to. Worth remembering that the main battle being fought at the time was "we can use inheritance for _everything_!" - and a big part of that was because there was a name for it.

Comment: I think this is a really good answer but it omits the main problems that arose out of the GoF (which I contend is a really good primer for OO design; specifically: Strategy). The biggest issue was that naming 'patterns' became a land grab. Most of these were really just either meaningless or bad ideas, to be frank. The next issue was that people started using 'pattern oriented design'. e.g. If you have problem a use pattern x. Then people would write a lot of insanely terrible code to try to glue it all together.  As you say, patterns were about communication and that went off the rails.

Comment: "Software design, especially good software design is far too varied to be meaningfully captured in patterns" -- I'd say this is true in any deep field, and yet there *is* value in having generalities to help in thinking and communicating about our designs (software or mechanical, or species, or behaviors). Coming up with generalities that are general enough yet specific enough is very hard.

Comment: "Especially in the small number of patterns people can actually remember – and they’re far too abstract for people to really remember more than a handful". Another way to say this is that GoF's patterns may be more useful for academics and professionals who are willing and able to invest the time into learning them: what they're good for and what they're not. This goes along with J Coffin's comment that these patterns didn't gain enough critical mass to help much in communication.

Comment: Churchill's quote could easily be applied to GoF Patterns: "No one pretends that democracy is perfect or all-wise. Indeed it has been said that democracy is the worst form of Government except for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time..."

Answer (score 111):

> I am having the impression that these 23 patterns should be only a small sample of something much larger which I like to call the Pattern Space.

This is the dreadful assumption that is propagated by neophyte programmers everywhere, programmers who think that they can write a program merely by stitching together software patterns.  It doesn't work that way.  If there is such a "pattern space," you can assume that its size is effectively infinite.

Design patterns (in the GoF sense) have but one purpose: **to compensate for deficiencies in the programming language you are using.**

Design patterns are neither universal nor comprehensive.  If you change to a different, more expressive programming language, most of the patterns in the GoF book become both unnecessary and undesirable.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but my question is not about the usefulness of patterns which I think is rather limited. It is about the discrepancy between the persistently high popularity of patterns and the lack of progress in that area.

By the way, I don't think it's neophyte profgrammers that propagate patterns, it''s managers who think that it's a way to make programming routine work that can be done by less educated and thus cheaper people.

Comment: You're blaming managers for this mindset?  I hadn't considered that before.  The popularity problem isn't hard to understand; popularity and effectiveness don't track together.   See http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Parkinsons-law-of-triviality-bikeshedding  The lack of progress is because pattern programming doesn't work.

Comment: It's not the managers that are to 'blame', it's more or less technical people who simplify things and give managers the impression that every idiot will write quality code if he can apply a few design patterns. This caused design patterns to become the number one topic in many job interviews.

Comment: "Design patterns (in the GoF sense) have but one purpose: to compensate for deficiencies in the programming language you are using."  I keep hearing this, but have yet to see it justified.  Every supposed justification of it just points to a handful of patterns that are easier to implement in languages with some feature -- usually Visitor and perhaps Singleton -- and leaves the vast majority of patterns untouched, just implying that they too can be made redundant by better languages. But how do we know? What language feature makes Observer irrelevant? Chain of Responsibility? Composite?

Comment: @Jules First class functions alone eliminate a sizable chunk of them, including Chain of Responsibility (it's just composition of a list of functions). Functional reactive programming eliminates the Observer pattern. The Composite pattern is just a less-rigorously specified definition of monoids, and languages with typeclasses and a focus on algebraic laws give powerful tools for working with monoids. I could list plenty more but you get the idea.

Comment: @Jules: I believe the original GoF book listed iterator as a pattern, but now its transformation into language feature is basically complete in every remotely OOP language.

Comment: @FrankPuffer That hasn't been my (admittedly limited) experience. I was introduced to the Gang of Four book by a *programmer*. Someone who I think is generally rather pragmatic, interestingly enough. I've never heard of managers even being interested in them. I think it much more likely that they are propagated by the same kinds of programmers who believe that OOP or TDD magically make your code better without having to think about what you're doing.

Comment: +1 for the "dreadful assumption". Design Patterns are not Pokemon cards. You don't win the game by just having and playing the right cards at the right time.

Comment: @Jack First class functions are at an entirely different level of abstraction, though: first class functions are basically equivalent to objects, not design patterns.  That's like saying chain of responsibility isn't necessary because you have objects.  Functional reactive programming is just an alternative pattern that provides similar functionality to using observers.  And monoids, monads, functors, applicative functors, and all the rest are just other design patterns too.  Yes, having typeclasses for these is a benefit, but it doesn't eliminate the pattern, it just moves it into a library.

Comment: @Kevin - Sure.  Iterator is usually included as a standard part of the library of most languages, and many languages have features that interact with it directly.  It doesn't stop it being a pattern, though.  It just makes it easier to implement and use.

Comment: @Jules maybe not exactly what you're talking about, but both VB6 & the .Net languages have built in observers via events.

Comment: @RubberDuck how is having the pattern already implemented making the pattern obsolete? It's still the design pattern being implemented. Different sets of language features might lead to different  implementations of the pattern, but the pattern itself is still there. Patterns are there to ease communication by giving names to reoccurring strategies that's commonly used. Point in case, the .NET classes are called `ObservableSomething<T>` which makes it easy to understand their purpose, because it uses the commonly known pattern name. A pattern is an idea, not an exact implementation.

Comment: @null the point is that we *don't* have to implement the pattern, as it's baked into the language. I already said that maybe it wasn't precisely what Jules was asking for, but I find it to be an example of how this language is less deficient (in this particular area) than others.

Comment: @Jules You're stretching the definition of design pattern though. If you call basically every programming construct a design pattern, then sure, design patterns are still in wide use! But that's not the definition most people think of, nor the one used in GoF.

Comment: @FrankPuffer: do all patterns compensate programming language features? I was unsure about that question, too, but found this interesting link:  http://wiki.c2.com/?AreDesignPatternsMissingLanguageFeatures

Comment: @Jules: What is a Program? A solution to a re-occuring problem. What is a Design Pattern? A solution to a re-occuring problem. Why is it not a program? Because we can't express it as a program. Ergo, a Design Pattern is a solution to a re-occuring problem that should rather be a Program, not a Design Pattern, but can't be a Program, because the language is not expressive enough to express the Program. Example: not too long ago, "Subroutine Call" was a Design Pattern! Nowadays, it is a language feature.

Comment: @DocBrown Are you sure it's not the opposite ? I mean people taking design pattern and make them as a feature instead of having to implement them again and again ?

Comment: @Walfrat: I have no clue what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - "What is a Program? A solution to a re-occuring problem. What is a Design Pattern? A solution to a re-occuring problem."  I disagree with this; a design pattern is an abstract description of a general approach to solving a large class of re-occuring high-level problems.  And the restriction that the problems are high level is a critical one ... it is this that means that we don't generally consider Subroutine Call (or Heap Allocated Object, or Statically Allocated Variable, or ...) to be a pattern, and not the fact that it is implemented in our languages.  And the reason ...

Comment: ... that's important is that design patterns are supposed to be a language we can use to document the decisions made when designing a program, but the above patterns aren't really useful at that level of abstraction.

Comment: @Jules "a design pattern is an abstract description of a general approach to solving a large class of re-occuring high-level problems". You could easily replace "design pattern" with "programming language" in that definition. There are many high-level language features, e.g. modules.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: you are oversimplifying, and playing with words. Not all design patterns are "not a program because we cannot express them as a program".

Comment: @DocBrown How about "not a library because we cannot express them as a library"? If a pattern really is a solution to a recurrent problem then you'd ideally want it implemented as a library, with the "holes" in the pattern where you fill in your customsations being parameters; you just "call" the pattern on the things you want to apply it to. But ideas for programmings solutions are expressed as patterns rather than libraries precisely when the holes are the "wrong shape" for what the host language allows you to abstract over.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48546/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-harvey-did-the-gang-of-four-really-thoroughly-exp).

Comment: @Ben You cannot possibly express the Visitor pattern as a library. If you could express all design patterns as libraries, we wouldn't have any design patterns, only libraries. There is a difference.

Comment: @EJP: I don't see the logic in this claim. One design pattern can be implemented differently by different libraries (and even has to, because no library can practically work with all technologies/languages). These libraries all employ the same structure and comparable algorithm at some point - and that common structure *is* the design pattern.

Comment: Do you recommend to avoid learning design patterns?

Comment: @030 I don't recommend to avoid learning anything.  Just don't expect to become a programming expert solely by learning "software patterns."

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I am now learning all java keywords by hard and learning SOLID. At the moment the SOLID principles seem to be a bridge too far at the moment. I wrote several programs, but I am not happy about the quality. I have to admit that design patterns would help significantly, but now I see that more steps are required. I am always interested about why and when to make certain decisions. I read books that explained what is an array and what is a String etc., but I basically want to rationalize the decisions. I thought that DP would say if this then use singleton.

Comment: @030: SOLID, Design Patterns and DI will all make more sense once you know Java better.  Most new software developers learn these concepts too early, before they know Java well enough to understand them, and get confused as a result.  Learn the `new` keyword in Java.  Learn it well, so that when you remove it using an IoC container, you'll understand why.  The better you get at Java, the better you'll use these patterns.  Even concert pianists practice the scales.

Comment: @Jules There are languages where you can just say that something equals the value of something else. `window.width = textbox.width + button.width + border.width*2 + 20;` and that relationship will be maintained even if the button changes width. I don't know any such languages, but they must exist.

Answer (score 65):

I think there are three factors that come into play here.

#### Lack of Critical Mass

First, a pattern is basically little more than giving a name to some code that implements a particular "chunk" of functionality. The only way that name provides much real value is if you can depend on *everybody* knowing what the name means so just by using the name, they immediately understand quite a lot about the code.

Patterns never established the critical mass they needed to accomplish that though. Rather the opposite, AAMOF. In the 20 (or so) years since the GoF book came out, I'm pretty sure I haven't seen as many as a dozen conversations in which everybody involved really knew enough design patterns for their use to improve communication.

To put it slightly more quaintly: design patterns failed specifically because they failed.

#### Too Many Patterns

I think the second major factor is that, if anything, they initially named too many patterns. In a fair number of cases, the differences between patterns are sufficiently subtle that it's next to impossible to say with real certainty whether a particular class fits one pattern or another (or maybe both--or perhaps neither).

The intent was that you'd be able to talk about code at a higher level. You'd be able to label a fairly large chunk of code as the implementation of a particular pattern. Simply by using that pre-defined name, everybody listening would usually know as much as they cared about that code, so you could move onto the next thing.

The reality tends to be nearly the opposite. Let's say you're in a meeting and tell them that this particular class is an Facade. Half the people in the meeting either never knew or have long since forgotten exactly what that means. One of them asks you to remind him of the exact difference(s) between a Facade and, say, a Proxy. Oh, and the couple of people who really do know patterns spend the rest of the meeting debating whether this should really be considered a Facade or "just" an Adapter (with that one guy still insisting that it seems like a Proxy to him).

Given that your intent was really just to say: "this code isn't very interesting; let's move on", trying to use the name of a pattern only added distraction, not value.

#### Lack of Interest

Most design patterns don't really deal with the interesting parts of code. They deal with things like: "how do I create these objects?", and "how do I get this object to talk to that one?" Memorizing pattern names for these (as well as the aforementioned arguments over details and such) is simply putting a lot of energy into things most programmers just don't care very much about.

To put it slightly differently: patterns deal with the things that are the same between lots of programs--but what really makes a program interesting is how it's *different* from other programs.

#### Summary

Design patterns failed because:

1. They failed to achieve critical mass.
2. Differentiation between patterns was insufficient to guarantee clarity.
3. They mostly dealt with parts of code almost nobody really cared about anyway.

Comment: "...but what really makes a program interesting is how it's different from other programs." I completely agree but for that you have to first get the same part right, maybe they just differ by some trivial aspect. If you relax a bit the need to name and identify patterns I'm convinced one sees patterns almost everyhwere. It's just that they do almost never come in their pure form but are always more or less adapted to the problem at hand.

Comment: Very good answer.

Comment: @Trilarion: Oh, I realize those parts of the code have to be written. They're a little like, say, the tires on your car. You pretty much need tires to drive at all--but most people still barely know the brand of tires on their car. This is asking that they learn special terminology for a tire with asymmetric diagonal grooves. Who knows--those might have saved my life once, but I still don't spend my life learning names for them.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The problem with your car tyre analogy is that you're a consumer of tyres but a producer of code. Your analogy explains why your customer doesn't care about design patterns but you'd be worried if the people who made the tyre didn't know the names for those asymmetric diagonal grooves. I'm not disputing your conclusion but I don't think your analogy supports it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Okay, then let's use a "producer side" version of the analogy. Does it matter that John who designs tires for Goodyear uses one word for that type of groove, but Pierre who works for Michelin uses an entirely different word? Does it matter that one uses a word referring only to the groove, but the other a word referring to a complete tire with horizontal grooves on one side of the center and diagonal grooves on the other?

Comment: Have they failed, though? You can tell someone "this is a singleton" or "this is a factory" and they know what you mean; maybe not the exact details.

Comment: @immibis: I would say mostly yes, they've failed. I'd say there are fewer than half a dozen patterns most programmers recognize. Singleton is well known, but actually only rarely applicable (at best). The name "Factory" was in common use long before "patterns" came along (I remember its use in the late 1970's or *very* early 1980's). Patterns were supposed to form a vocabulary, but currently they're about like my vocabulary in Greek--enough to (possibly) get myself in trouble, but certainly not enough to order off a menu, much less hold a meaningful conversation.

Answer (score 36):

#### Patterns are missing abstractions, simple patterns are abstracted, complex patterns are not recognized, so patterns are not useful (except a few high level ones).

I think Paul Graham said it best:

> When I see patterns in my programs, I consider it a sign of trouble. The shape of a program should reflect only the problem it needs to solve. Any other regularity in the code is a sign, to me at least, that I'm using abstractions that aren't powerful enough-- often that I'm generating by hand the expansions of some macro that I need to write.

When you recognize a pattern in your code, it means something repeats itself and you should use a better abstraction. If you don't have a better abstraction, you use the pattern as a workaround. Because newer programming languages provide better abstractions, patterns become much less useful.
Also simple patterns are often easily abstracted and complex patterns rarely recognized.
When a pattern becomes replaced by an abstraction, it does not mean that the concept behind the pattern disappears, but that the concept can be written explicitly instead of indirect and that it is no longer special compared to other code and it becomes no longer recognizable as a pattern.

Comment: Personally, I somehow really like this idea. But then, code should be readable by humans and people like patterns. Patterns help us finding our way around. Removing ***all*** patterns from our code will make it unreadable.

Comment: @Frank I think where PG is coming from is that a pattern is a 'smell' of an underlying function that you can abstract, & the fact that you haven't pulled it out into a function or macro is what's causing the repetition ― like if you didn't have a `String.replace` function, you could imagine it popping up as a pattern, but better to write it once rather than continuing to reimplement it. Agree that if you don't name these things properly it would make it harder to read, but when it's done right, code reads more declaratively IMO (e.g. the `getOrElse` style of option monads vs null checking)

Comment: Paul Graham's quote was about keeping your solutions DRY, which is different from the GoF "pattern" idea.  The GoF idea was about giving names to commonly used solutions.  We already were doing that long before the GoF published their book.  For example, I can tell my co-worker that I'm going to use a _queue_, and my co-worker immediately knows what I'm talking about without my having to explain the details of what a queue does or how it works.  But, see Michael Borgwardt's excellent answer, above.

Comment: In my opinion, this answer misunderstands what patterns are. A design pattern is an often encountered solution to a common problem. It isn't some code duplication. Say, take an iterator. You solve the problem of abstracting away the container so you can go through the elements inside it regardless of what the container is. Thus you create an iterator class which does that for each of your containers and make them implement a common interface. What's to abstract here? An iterator already is an abstraction. And, of course, it's implemented differently for all containers, so no code duplication.

Comment: The key part of Graham's quote is _often that I'm generating by hand the expansions of some macro that I need to write._ This references Lisp macros specifically. There is only so much abstraction one can do without macros.

Comment: @jameslarge yes but you don't expect to have to reimplement a queue each time, you just use a library function, thats PGs point, with a more powerful language patterns become reified as abstractions, in PGs case with Lisp that might often be as a macro, in other powerful languages it will be other powerful features e.g. typeclasses

Comment: "When you recognize a pattern in your code, it means something repeats itself and you should use a better abstraction" -> Unusual yet interesting opinion. After a minute of brainf*ck, I agree with this POV.

Comment: This is a fair answer when looking within a body of code. But I think the stronger case for design patterns is when communicating across multiple bodies of code.  I can say "this interface specifies a factory method" without there being any possibility of combining the interface or any of its implementers into any other class hierarchy or using any better method of abstraction.

Answer (score 13):

While I mostly agree with what others answered here, I personally think that a main reason for a not growing number of patterns is that patterns loose their meaning when there are countless ones. The nice thing with these few patterns is, that they cover a lot of problem domains in a standard way. If you'd focus on an endless pattern domain you'd end up with no pattern at all. It's a bit like "how long is the coast line of an island?". If you measure on a map you come with a decent number. But if you try to get more exact and got to a finer resolution, you will find that the length increases more and more to infinity (or uncertainty; how would you measure the exact border with tides and on atomic level?).

Comment: Right, patterns can only work if there are not too many of them. But why are the GoF ones still the most popular ones? Some of them are now considered as antipatterns by many people (Singleton, Builder, etc.). This should make room for new, more useful patterns without increasing the total number.

Comment: I guess it's like the 10 commandments. The source is only 2 chars away (GOF, GOE, GOD) xD

Comment: Yes, and it sometimes seems like modern software engineering relates to GoF like medieval scholastics relates to Aristotle.

Answer (score 12):

Something that none of the other answers mention that is also relevant:

The rise of dynamically-typed languages.

When the book first came out there was serious discussion that Java was just too slow to do real work in. Now Java is frequently used over more expressive languages *because* of its speed. Maybe Ruby, Python, JavaScript, et al are still too slow for some important classes of applications, but by-and-large they're fast enough for most purposes. And JavaScript at least is actually getting faster despite having more features packed in every release.

The original GoF book had the patterns in both smalltalk and c++, and if memory serves the patterns were always shorter in smalltalk and sometimes significantly so. Some of the features of the classic design patterns are really ways to add dynamic features to a statically typed system (like the already discussed AbstractFactory, in which you instantiate the correct class based on runtime data). Others are so much shorter in dynamic languages that they simply meld into idiomatic use of the language itself.

Answer (score 11):

It *did* happen. Dozens if not hundreds of books were published in what looked like an attempt to reduce the whole of computer science to design patterns, as publishers and authors attempted to jump on (or create) yet another bandwagon. I have a shelf of them. Never consulted since first scanned, and yes I was a sucker, because there was little or nothing in there of any actual use or that wasn't already well known (see for example Type Object, which is nothing more than third normal form expressed over a dozen pages instead of one paragraph), and because obviously the fewer patterns the better: a point which eluded most of the practicioners. Indeed, when I posted a rebuttal of Type Object, I was instructed to recast my text *as a design pattern.* True story. Which also shows another deficiency of the project: no review or exclusion or rejection mechanism.

As a matter of fact the GoF didn't actually attempt to 'thoroughly explore Design Patterns'. Rather, they were engaged on a much larger project: to introduce 'pattern language' into CS, with all its bizarre notational arcana of Forces, Participants, etc., which simply failed, because it was fundamentally misconceived, as well as being pointless.

What they *did* accomplish, which was useful, was two things:

- publish several useful tricks such as the Visitor pattern
- provide a standard set of names which has largely stuck: Factory, Adapter, Iterator, ... If you look at CORBA, which was designed immediately beforehand, you will see the value of this: all sorts of 'foreign' names such as Interceptor, Servant, Broker, ...

Another useful concept that arose was the 'anti-pattern', e.g. 'log and throw'. The project, like many fads in CS, was derailed by its own evangelism and by being misguidedly adopted as yet another CS religion, and it went the way of most such religions: useful in parts, but certainly 'no silver bullet' ((c) Fred Brooks, 1965). Sad that we have to keep rediscovering that every few years really.

Comment: Is it still sad if it resulted in this discussion (and all that entails)

Comment: @r3wt *Non sequitur.* What I said is sad is the IT industry's weakness for  thinking every new development is going be the mythical silver bullet, and incidentally for trashing some of its own prior work.

Comment: look at it from a different perspective. It's not sad for me reading your answer, learning not to repeat the mistake. so what you take for granted is actually very useful to others.

Answer (score 6):

There were/are several books titled PLoP ([Pattern Languages of Program Design](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pattern+Languages+of+Program+Design)) which are each an anthology of papers presented at [an annual conference](http://hillside.net/conferences/plop).

Reading the books, I found some of the patterns were interesting and new to me, some of them standards (e.g. "half object plus protocol").

So no, the GoF's collection wasn't exhaustive, and inspired/inspires people to collect/describe/discover/invent new ones.

The "only 12 additional patterns listed in the Wikipedia article" presumably aren't a complete collection either: i.e. there are others documented elsewhere, e.g. in the PLoP books and maybe elsewhere too.

Comment: Yes, you can find descriptions of hundreds of patterns if you search for them. But none of these seems to be near as popular as the GoF ones.

Comment: It was because I liked reading the GoF book that I read more (books) when they were published (later).

Comment: @FrankPuffer I bet the patterns are popular, even if the names aren't.

Answer (score 5):

The  Gang of Four (GoF) book contains most patterns that an experienced programmer in a none functional language have in their tool belt.     It is like the basic set of tools that all builders know how to use.   The primary contribution of the book was to **give well defined name to the patterns that were in common use by most experienced programmers** at the time and hence aid communication between programmers discussing design options.

You expect that an electrician to have some tools that a normal builder does not, likewise you would expect that a WPF programmer to know the design patterns for “Dependency Properties”, or a “SQL Programmer” to know the design pattern for using triggers to create audit data.

**However we don’t think of these as “Design patterns” due to them only being used with one technology.**

Some more modem design pattern books are [“Refactoring, Improving the Design of Existing Code (Martin Fowler)”](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201485672) and [“Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (Robert C. Martin)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)” **Both of these books present the contents as transformations you make to your current code, rather than as “pre canned reusable design”, however they are just as much “design patterns”.**

Answer (score 5):

Here is an interview with Erich Gamma where he reflect on their selection of patterns and what they'd change today (well today as of 10 years ago, haha).

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1404056

> ***Larry:*** How would you refactor "Design Patterns"?
>
> **Erich:** We did this exercise in 2005. Here are some notes from our session. We have found that the object-oriented design principles and most of the patterns haven't changed since then. We wanted to change the categorization, add some new members and also drop some of the patterns. Most of the discussion was about changing the categorization and in particular which patterns to drop.
>
> When discussing which patterns to drop, we found that we still love them all. (Not really—I'm in favor of dropping Singleton. Its use is almost always a design smell.)
>
> So here are some of the changes:
>
> - Interpreter and Flyweight should be moved into a separate category that we referred to as "Other/Compound" since they really are different beasts than the other patterns. Factory Method would be generalized to Factory.
> - The categories are: Core, Creational, Peripheral and Other. The intent here is to emphasize the important patterns and to separate them from the less frequently used ones.
> - The new members are: Null Object, Type Object, Dependency Injection, and Extension Object/Interface (see "Extension Object" in Pattern Languages of Program Design 3, Addison- Wesley, 1997).
> - These were the categories:
>
>   - Core: Composite, Strategy, State, Command, Iterator, Proxy, Template Method, Facade
>   - Creational: Factory, Prototype, Builder, Dependency Injection
>   - Peripheral: Abstract Factory, Visitor, Decorator, Mediator, Type Object, Null Object, Extension Object
>   - Other: Flyweight, Interpreter

Comment: Why are you downvoting me? Please explain in a comment so I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The actual patterns in the book are sometimes really useful, but they are really just instances of a more powerful tool that the book gives you: a deep understanding of when and where it's better to cut monolithic code in independent parts separated and regulated by an interface.

When you learn that skill, you realize that you don't need to remember the exact details of every single pattern, as you can always cut the solution you are implementing in the way that best fits its purpose. So the idea of writing down more and more patterns seems very academic and pointless.

Comment: Good point, however I doubt that many people understand the book (or patterns in general) that way.

Comment: @lud1977 if we don't record history, what prevents the future from falling into the same traps? thus, it must always be recorded. its not pointless.

Answer (score 2):

> So I expected the number of known and documented design patterns to
>   grow significantly.
>
> It did not happen. More than 20 years after the GoF book came out,
>   only 12 additional patterns are listed in the Wikipedia article, most
>   of which are much less popular than the original ones. (I did not
>   include the concurrency patterns here because they cover a specific
>   topic.)

The GoF book and Wikipedia are hardly the only source of known design patterns. If you just search for "design patterns" in Amazon.com you get hundreds of books (try this [search](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=node%3D5&field-keywords=design%20patterns&lo=stripbooks&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A5%2Ck%3Adesign%20patterns)). I guess they only list the most well known pattern in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

So the problem is not that there are not enough documented design patterns. Rather there are so many that nobody can memorize them all and most programmers recognize only a few. The big promise of common pattern language breaks down at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably plenty of structures that haven't yet been thought of. As long as people are developing software, there will be design challenges to overcome. Some of those may well be solved using clever new patterns that others could make use of.

Programming languages have developed and progressed to abstract away the most commonly used patterns. Those patterns still exist in the design of the languages. So they may be ignored today, but that doesn't make them unimportant.

Is the knowledge of how to construct a house suddenly unimportant once we have robots that can do it for us? I would argue no, it's not. It's less relevant, sure - and probably a lot less rewarding to study, since the demand did drop sharply, and no one else is studying it.

So no, I don't believe pattern space as you call it has been exhausted. As another answer pointed out, it's likely to be infinite. But as the demand for systems design dies down, as we increase the height of our tower of abstraction and the power of our programming languages - fewer and fewer people building away on the top tiers will pay attention to the details of how the tower was built.

Answer (score -2):

Patterns are infinite.. You can tweak each pattern or mix n match to create new ones.. Enterprise integration patterns are also well defined..so yes gof did take pain of documenting patterns using uml and created a standard for explaining them.. But for each domain patterns evolve and they also change for expressive language like python or scala..