# Applicability of Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: architecture, single-responsibility, event

I recently came by a seemingly trivial architectural problem. I had a simple repository in my code that was called like this (code is in C#):

```cs
var user = /* create user somehow */;
_userRepository.Add(user);
/* do some other stuff*/
_userRepository.SaveChanges();
```

`SaveChanges` was a simple wrapper that commits changes to database:

```cs
void SaveChanges()
{
    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    _logger.Log("User DB updated: " + someImportantInfo);
}
```

Then, after some time, I needed to implement new logic that would send email notifications every time a user was created in the system. Since there were many calls to `_userRepository.Add()` and `SaveChanges` around the system, I decided to update `SaveChanges` like this:

```cs
void SaveChanges()
{
    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    _logger.Log("User DB updated: " + someImportantInfo);
    foreach (var newUser in dataContext.GetAddedUsers())
    {
       _eventService.RaiseEvent(new UserCreatedEvent(newUser ))
    }
}
```

This way, external code could subscribe to UserCreatedEvent and handle the needed business logic that would send notifications.

But it was pointed out to me that my modification of `SaveChanges` violated the Single Responsibility principle, and that `SaveChanges` should just save and not fire any events.

Is this a valid point? It seems to me that the raising an event here is essentially the same thing as logging: just adding some side functionality to the function. And SRP does not prohibit you from using logging or firing events in your functions, it just says that such logic should be encapsulated in other classes, and it is OK for a repository to call these other classes.

Comment: Your retort is: "OK, so how would *you* write it so that it doesn't violate SRP but still allows a single point of modification?"

Comment: My observation is that raising an event does not add an additional responsibility.  In fact, quite the opposite: it **delegates the responsibility somewhere else.**

Comment: I think your coworker is right, but your question is valid and useful, so upvoted!

Comment: There's no such thing as a definitive definition of a Single Responsibility. The person pointing out that it violates SRP is correct using their personal definition and you are correct using your definition. I think your design is perfectly fine with the caveat that this event isn't a one-off whereby other similar functionality is done in different ways.  Consistency is far, far, far more important to pay attention to than some vague guideline like SRP which carried to the extreme ends up with tons of very easy to understand classes that nobody knows how to make work in a system.

Comment: Does `SaveChanges` update multiple users?

Comment: Possibly related: *[How do you determine how coarse or fine-grained a 'responsibility' should be when using the single responsibility principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2455705/25847)*

Comment: The method name says "SaveChanges" and then does more than just saving. That would surprise me. And I try to follow POLA - Principle of Least Astonishment. I would put the even raising code into the calling method -> `void callingMethod() { saveChanges(); raiseEvent(); } `

Comment: @Andrejs: you are right, that is why such a repo class should have a name like `NotifyingRepository` or `ObservableRepository` (see my answer below).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it can be a valid requirement to have a repository which fires certain events on certain actions like `Add` or `SaveChanges` - and I am not going to question this (like some other answers) just because your specific example of adding users and sending emails may look a bit contrived. In the following, let us assume this requirement is perfectly justified in the context of your system.

So **yes**, encoding the event mechanics as well as the logging as well as the saving into one method **violates the SRP**.  For lots of cases , it is probably an acceptable violation, especially when noone ever wants to distribute the maintenance responsibilities of "save changes" and "raise event" to different teams/maintainers. But lets assume one day someone wants to do exactly this, can it be resolved in a simple manner, maybe by putting the code of those concerns into different class libraries?

The solution to this is to let your original repository stay responsible for committing changes to database, nothing else, and make a **proxy** repository which has exactly the same public interface, reuses the original repository and adds the additional event mechanics to the methods.

```
// In EventFiringUserRepo:
public void SaveChanges()
{
  _basicRepo.SaveChanges();
   FireEventsForNewlyAddedUsers();
}

private void FireEventsForNewlyAddedUsers()
{
  foreach (var newUser in _basicRepo.DataContext.GetAddedUsers())
  {
     _eventService.RaiseEvent(new UserCreatedEvent(newUser))
  }
}
```

You can call the proxy class a `NotifyingRepository` or `ObservableRepository` if you like, along the lines of @Peter's [highly voted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/389259) (which actually does not tell how to resolve the SRP violation, only saying the violation is ok).

The new and the old repository class should both derive from a common interface, like [shown in the classic Proxy pattern description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Then, in your original code, initialize `_userRepository` by an object of the new `EventFiringUserRepo` class. That way, you keep the original repository separated from the event mechanics. If required, you can have the event firing repository and the original repository side-by-side and let the callers decide if they use either the former or the latter.

To adress one concern mentioned in the comments: *doesn't that lead to proxies on top of proxies on top of proxies, and so on?* Actually, adding the event mechanics creates a foundation to add further requirements of the "send emails" type by simply subscribing to the events, so sticking to the SRP with those requirements as well, without any additional proxies. But the one thing which has to be added once here is the event mechanics itself.

If this kind of separation is really worth it in the context of your system is something you and your reviewer have to decide by yourself. I probably would not separate the logging from the original code, neither by using another proxy not by adding a logger to the listener event, though it would be possible.

Comment: In addition to this answer. There are alternatives to proxies, like [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: I think you miss the point, its not that raising an event breaks the SRP its that raising an event only for "New" users requires the repo to be responsible for knowing what constitutes a "New" user rather than a "Newly Added to Me" user

Comment: @Ewan: please read the question again. It was about a place in code which does certain actions which needs to be coupled with other actions outside of the responsivility of that object. And putting the action and the event raising in one place was questioned by a peer reviewer as breaking the SRP. The example of "saving new users" is only for the purpose of demonstration, call the example contrived if you like, but that is IMHO not the point of the question.

Comment: This is the best/correct answer IMO. Not only does it maintain SRP, but it also maintains the Open/Closed principle. And think of all of the automated tests that changes within the class could break. Modifying existing tests when *new* functionality is added is a big smell.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, and a good illustration of the OCP.  But, let's extrapolate.  In a week, they want to add a "add this user to the you get a month free tier", and, after that month, add "don't forget to charge their credit card since they forgot to unsubscribe".  Do you suggest "proxies all the way down"?  (This is where I fear the OCP starts to fall apart)

Comment: @user949300: once an event mechanics was added to the repo, all other kinds of requirements of this type don't need another proxy, they can simply subscribe to the events.

Comment: Doc, that just hides the issue on the listeners.  Do you write proxies for them to add capabilities?  How do you keep SRP in them?

Comment: @user949300: you know that in C# events usually support multicasting? So each event can have multiple listeners. No need to write additional proxies for them.

Comment: Yeah, there would never be a problem with duplicate listeners, zombie listeners, circular listeners.  :-(. I agree that listeners are cleaner, this is a nice design, but something has to set them up properly.  It's like FP "get rid of state".  A good idea **where possible**.  But some state needs to continue on and something needs to hold it.

Comment: How does this solution work if there is a transaction in progress? When that is going on, `SaveChanges()` does not actually create the database record, and it could end up getting rolled back. Seems like you'd have to either override `AcceptAllChanges` or subscribe to the TransactionCompleted event.

Comment: @JohnWu: that may be a problem of the original code, or not, you need to ask the OP (from the question description I would guess `_dataContext.SaveChanges` does a commit itself). My solution makes the assumption that the semantics of the original code is ok, and adresses the actual question about the SRP without changing the semantics.

Comment: @user949300: you may have missed that the idea to add event mechanics to the repo for allowing to add additional business requirements in a separated manner is already in the original question.  But the one-and-only thing which cannot be separated out by such an event mechanics is the event mechanics itself. My answer just adresses this problem in terms of the SRP and does not question the OP's idea of using events.

Comment: @DocBrown, your proposed solution looks more like a Decorator pattern than a Proxy because it focuses on adding functions to an object rather than controlling access (distinction taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618841/1474386))

Comment: @AndreBorges: sorry, I forgot to add access modifiers to my code snippet, see my edit. The idea is to keep the public interface exactly the same, so this is definitely a Proxy, not a Decorator.

Answer (score 29):

Sending a notification that the persistent data store changed seems like a sensible thing to do when saving.

Of course you shouldn't treat Add as a special case - you'd have to fire events for Modify and Delete as well. It's the special treatment of the "Add" case that smells, forces the reader to explain why it smells, and ultimately leads some readers of the code to conclude it must violate SRP.

A "notifying" repository that can be queried, changed, and fires events on changes, is a perfectly normal object. You can expect to find multiple variations thereof in pretty much any decently sized project.

---

But is a "notifying" repository actually what you need? You mentioned C#: Many people would agree that using a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<>` instead of `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` when the latter is all you need is all kinds of bad and wrong, but few would immediately point to SRP.

What you are doing now is swapping your `UserList _userRepository` with an `ObservableUserCollection _userRepository`. If that's the best course of action or not depends on the application. But while it unquestionably makes the `_userRepository` considerably less lightweight, in my humble opinion it doesn't violate SRP.

Comment: The problem with using `ObservableCollection`for this case is, it triggers the equivalent event not at the call to `SaveChanges`, but at the call to `Add`, which would lead to a very different behaviour than the one shown in the example. See my answer how to keep the original repo lightweight, and still stick to the SRP by keeping the semantics intact.

Comment: @DocBrown I invoked the known classes `ObservableCollection<>` and `List<>` for comparison and context. I did not mean to recommend using the actual classes for either the internal implementation or the external interface.

Comment: Ok, but even if the OP would add events to "Modify" and "Delete" (which I think the OP left out to keep the question concise, for the sake of simplicity), I think a reviewer could easily come to the conclusion of an SRP violation. It is probably an acceptable one, but none which cannot be resolved if required.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it is a violation of the single responsibility principle and a valid point.

A better design would be to have a separate process retrieve 'new users' from the repository and send the emails. Keeping track of which users have been sent an email, failures, resends, etc., etc.

This way you can handle errors, crashes and the like as well as avoiding your repository grabbing every requirement which has the idea that events happen "when something is committed to the database".

The repository doesn't know that a user you add is a new user. Its responsibility is simply storing the user.

It's probably worth expanding on the comments below.

> The repository doesn't know that a user you add is a new user - yes it
>   does, it has a method called Add. Its semantics implies that all added
>   users are new users. Combine all the arguments passed to Add before
>   calling Save - and you get all new users

Incorrect. You are conflating "Added to the Repository" and "New".

"Added to the Repository" means just what it says. I can add and remove and re-add users to various repositories.

"New" is a state of a user defined by business rules.

Currently the business rule might be "New == just been added to the repository", but that doesn't mean it's not a separate responsibility to know about and apply that rule.

You have to be careful to avoid this kind of database-centric thinking. You will have edge case processes which add non-new users to the repository and when you send emails to them all the business will say "Of course those are not 'new' users! The *actual* rule is X"

> This answer is IMHO quite missing the point: the repo is exactly the
>   one central place in the code which knows when new users are added

Incorrect. For the reasons above, plus it's not a central location unless you actually include the email sending code in the class rather than just raising an event.

You will have applications which use the repository class, but don't have the code to send the email. When you add users in those applications the email will not be sent.

Comment: _The repository doesn't know that a user you add is a new user_ - yes it does, it has a method called `Add`. Its semantics implies that all added users are new users. Combine all the arguments passed to `Add` before calling `Save` - and you get all new users.

Comment: I like this suggestion. However, pragmatism prevails over purity. Depending on the circumstances, adding an entirely new architectural layer to an existing application can be difficult to justify if all you need to do is literally send a single email when a user is added.

Comment: But the event is not saying user added. It says user created. If we consider naming things properly and we agree with the semantical differences between add and create, then the event in the snippet is either wrong named or missplaced. I don't think the reviewer had anything against notyfing repositories. Probably It was concerned about the kind of event and its side effects.

Comment: @Andre New to the repo, but not necessarily "new" in the business sense. its the conflation of these two ideas that's hiding the extra responsibility from first glance. I might import a tonne of old users to my new repository, or remove and re-add a user etc. There will be business rules about what a "new user" is beyond "has been added to the dB"

Comment: @Ewan, I agree that determining business sense is not the repository's job, but my repository does not do that, event handler does. Okay, my repository does fire event called `UserCreatedEvent`, but to avoid confusion I could rename it to `UserAddedToRepositoryEvent`, and event handler could decide if a certain event is considered to be "a new user". Currently, every event would qualify, but if business rules change (and they might, as you correctly mentioned) - then I would only have to change event handler, not the repository.

Comment: @AndreBorges yes, that would avoid the technical violation, but it's still not a great solution, what if you have "new" users that don't trigger the event, or add users when the emailer isn't listening? You are still using the event _as if_ it captures the business logic

Comment: @Ewan, if I have "new" users that don't need email notifications, then my event handler would have to deal with that logic. My event handler would have a method like `bool NeedToSendEmail(event)`. All this logic lives outside the repo, and the repo's job is only to raise an event "Oh, something changed inside me". And how to _handle_ this event (or does it need to be handled at all) - is the responsibility of external code. I really don't see any harm in repository _raising_ an event if it is not responsible for the way it would be handled.

Comment: @AndreBorges "what if you have "new" users that don't trigger the event, or add users when the emailer isn't listening?"

Comment: I guess my first comment was not clear enough: IMHO this answer focusses way too much on the specific example ("new users" and "emails"), where a possible solution may indeed be to decouple both processes in time, which makes it possible to decouple them in code as well. But that is IMHO loosing track of the core question: given there is an additional process which needs to be coupled (in time) by events to the repo's `SaveChanges` method, how can the "event sending" be implemented without violating the SRP?

Comment: @DocBrown even if time based coupling is required you don't need or want to couple it to the repository. The thing that just created a user can also raise events and likely has the "knowing about new users" responsiblity

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Your answer isn't a journalistic interview.  If you have edits, incorporate them naturally into your answer without creating the whole "breaking news" effect.  We're not a discussion forum.

Comment: @Ewan: well, maybe there is already such a "thing" (=outer context), or not. But if not, one can create such a "thing" - as a proxy, which wraps the original repo using an identical interface.  Exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @DocBrown I don't think that addresses the problem at all.

Comment: @Ewan: well, we can surely agree that your answer adresses a different problem than mine, let the OP decide who understood better what they really had in mind with the question.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this a valid point?

Yes it is, although it depends a lot on the structure of your code. I don't have the full context so I will try to talk in general.

> It seems to me that the raising an event here is essentially the same thing as logging: just adding some side functionality to the function.

It absolutely isn't. Logging is not part of the business flow, it can be disabled, it shouldn't cause (business) side effects and should not influence the state and heath of your application in any way, even if you were for some reason not able to log anything anymore. Now compare that with the logic you added.

> And SRP does not prohibit you from using logging or firing events in your functions, it just says that such logic should be encapsulated in other classes, and it is OK for a repository to call these other classes.

SRP works in tandem with ISP (S and I in SOLID). You end up with many classes and methods that do very specific things and nothing else. They are very focused, very easy to update or replace, and in general easy(er) to test. Of course in practice you'll also have a few bigger classes that deal with the orchestration: they will have a number of dependencies, and they will focus not on atomised actions, but on business actions, which may require multiple steps. As long as the business context is clear, they can too be called single responsibility, but as you correctly said, as the code grows, you may want to abstract some of it into new classes / interfaces.

Now back to your particular example. If you absolutely must send a notification whenever a user is created and maybe even perform other more specialised actions, then you could create a separate service that encapsulates this requirement, something like `UserCreationService`, which exposes one method, `Add(user)`, which handles both the storage (the call to your repository) and the notification as a single business action. Or do it in your original snippet, after `_userRepository.SaveChanges();`

Comment: _Logging is not part of the business flow_ - how is this relevant in the context of SRP? If the purpose of my event would be to send new user data to Google Analytics - then disabling it would have the same business effect as disabling logging: not critical, but pretty upsetting. What is the rule of a thumb for adding/not adding new logic to a function? "Will disabling it cause major business side effects?"

Comment: `If the purpose of my event would be to send new user data to Google Analytics - then disabling it would have the same business effect as disabling logging: not critical, but pretty upsetting `. What if you are firing premature events causing fake "news". What if the analytics are taking into account "users" that were not finally created due to errors with the DB transaction? What if the company is making decisions upon false premises, backed by imprecise data? You are too focused on the technical side of the issue. *"Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees'"*

Comment: @Laiv, you are making a valid point, but this is not the point of my question, or this answer. The question is whether this is a valid solution in the context of SRP, so let's assume there are no DB transaction errors.

Comment: You are basically asking me to tell you what you want to hear. I just give you scope. A wider scope for you to decide whether SRP matters or not because SRP is useless without the proper context. IMO the way you are approaching the concern is incorrect because you are only focusing on the technical solution. You should give enough relevance to the whole context. And yes, DB might fail. There's a chance for it to happen and you should not omit that, because as you know, *things happen* and these things could change your mind regarding doubts about SRP or other good practices.

Comment: That said, remember that principles are not rules written in stone. They are permeable (adaptive). As you can see, they are open to interpretation. Your reviewer has an interpretation and you have another. Try to see what you see, resolve his/her doubts and concerns, or let him/her solve yours. You will not find the "right" answer here. The correct answer is up to you and your reviewer to find, asking first to the requirements (functional and non-functional) of the project.

Answer (score 4):

SRP is, theoretically, about **people**, as Uncle Bob explains in his article [The Single Responsibility Principle](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html). <sub>Thanks Robert Harvey for providing it in your comment.</sub>

The correct question is:

#### Which "stakeholder" added the "send emails" requirement?

If that stakeholder is also in charge of data persistence (unlikely but possible) then this does not violate SRP.  Otherwise, it does.

Comment: Interesting - I never heard of this interpretation of the SRP. Do you have any pointers to more information / literature about this interpretation?

Comment: @sleske: [From Uncle Bob himself](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html): *"And this gets to the crux of the Single Responsibility Principle. **This principle is about people.***

*When you write a software module, you want to make sure that when changes are requested, those changes can only originate from a single person, or rather, a single tightly coupled group of people representing a single narrowly defined business function."*

Comment: Thanks Robert.  IMO, The name "Single Responsibility Principle" is terrible, as it sounds simple, but too few people follow up on what is the intended meaning of "responsibility".  Kind of like how OOP has mutated from many of it's original concepts, and is now a fairly meaningless term.

Comment: Yep.  That's what happened to the term REST.  Even Roy Fielding says people are using it wrong.

Comment: Though the cite is related, I think this answer misses that the "send emails" requirement is none of the direct requirements of which the SRP violation question is about. However, by saying *"Which "stakeholder" added the "raise event" requirement"*, this answer would become more related to the actual question. I modified my own answer a little bit to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2):

While technically there's nothing wrong with repositories notifying events, I would suggest looking at it from a functional point of view where its convenience rises some concerns.

> *Creating a user, deciding what's a new user is and its persistence are 3 different things*.

<sup>*Premise of mine*</sup>

Consider the previous premise before deciding whether the repository is the proper place to notify business events (regardless of the SRP). Note that I said *business event* because to me `UserCreated` has a different connotation than `UserStored` or `UserAdded` <sup>1</sup>. I would also consider each of those events to be addressed to different audiences.

On one side, creating users is a business-specific rule that might or might not involve persistence. It might involve more business operations, involving more database/network operations. Operations the persistence layer is unaware of. The persistence layer doesn't have enough context to decide whether the use case ended successfully or not.

On the flip side, it's not necessarily true that `_dataContext.SaveChanges();` has persisted the user successfully. It will depend on the database's transaction span. For instance, it could be true for databases like MongoDB, which transactions are atomic, but it could not, for traditional RDBMS implementing ACID transactions where there could be more transactions involved and yet to be committed.

> Is this a valid point?

It could be. However, I would dare to say that it's not only a matter of SRP (technically speaking), it's also a matter of convenience (functionally speaking).

- *Is it convenient to fire business events from components unaware of the business operations in progress?*
- *Do they represent the right place as much as the right moment to do it?*
- *Should I allow these components to orchestrate my business logic through notifications like this?*
- *Could I invalidate the side effects caused by premature events?* <sup>2</sup>

> It seems to me that the raising an event here is essentially the same
>   thing as logging

Absolutely not. Logging is meant to have no side effects, however, as you suggested the event `UserCreated` is likely to cause other business operations to happen. Like notifications. <sup>3</sup>

> it just says that such logic should be encapsulated in other classes,
>   and it is OK for a repository to call these other classes

Not necessarily true. SRP is not a class-specific concern only. It operates at different levels of abstractions, like layers, libraries and systems! It's about cohesion, about keeping together what changes for the same reasons [by the hand of the same stakeholders](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html). If the user creation (*use case*) changes it's likely the moment and the reasons for the event to happen also changes.

---

<sup>1: Naming things adequately also matters.</sup>

<sup>2: Say we sent `UserCreated` after `_dataContext.SaveChanges();`, but the whole database transaction failed later due to connection issues or constraints violations. Be careful with premature broadcasting of events, because its side effects can be hard to undo (if that is even possible).</sup>

3: Notification processes not treated adequately might cause you to fire notifications that can not be undone/sup>

Comment: +1 Very good point about the transaction span. It can be premature to assert the user has been created, because rollbacks can happen; and unlike with a log, it's likely some other part of the app does something with the event.

Comment: Exactly. Events denote certainity. Something happened but it's over.

Comment: @Laiv: Except when they don't.  Microsoft has all sorts of events prefixed with `Before` or `Preview` that make no guarantees at all about certainty.

Comment: Hmm. I have never seen this sort of events. Would you mind sharing some references?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Microsoft code is not an example I would advise someone to follow. It tends to be incredibly convoluted, making it difficult to understand (read) or maintain.

Comment: @jpmc26: Without an alternative, your suggestion is not helpful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh, that's easy. Python code is, in my opinion, the best model to follow. =) You do have to understand some things about *why* you don't need as much boiler plate in it to be able to apply the principles in languages like C# and Java (since applying them can sometimes generate some boilerplate that you wouldn't need in Python), but I still find that I've learned the best ways of organizing code from it.

Comment: @jpmc26: So your answer is "change to a completely different development ecosystem with an entirely different set of tools and performance characteristics."  Call me contrary, but I would imagine this is infeasible for the vast majority of development efforts.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, my answer is, "Learn to think like Python developers think and then apply those lessons in C#." Sadly, this is not a common approach, even though I can personally attest to the improvement to my own C# code doing it. (That is true in spite of the ecosystem, and I find other devs that I've worked with also appreciated the approaches I used and suggested.)

Comment: @jpmc26: Because that approach is also infeasible.  You don't put sports car wheels on a pickup truck and call it a Porsche.

Comment: @jpmc26: Events are not second-class citizens; they're essentially a specialized form of a first-class function.  Nobody argues that first-class functions are bad and that you should eliminate them from your programs.  I'll grant you that Microsoft's event system is a bit hard to follow, but that doesn't indict events as a general technique.  Events are simply one implementation of the Observer Pattern.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, it isn't infeasible. I've *done* it, with much success, and to the delight of my coworkers. Contrast with crappy MS approaches that lead to things like MVC not parsing our URL parameters into a list model unless we add an attribute to tell it to look there. (Wat.) MS code is *confusing*, in both structure and behavior. Python code tends to be much more straightforward, and writing *straightforward* code is the primary lesson I applied. As for patterns, [well...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/335894/92517)

Comment: @jpmc26: Presumably, your assertions refer to things like MVVM, which prefer techniques like data binding over events, an approach with which I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Frankly, I abandoned the whole MVC, MVVM, pick-your-acronym-soup debates years ago. I didn't find them at all helpful for writing straightforward code. If my code happens to conform to them by coincidence, that's fine, but at the end of the day, what I try to do is make my code so obvious that any idiot could make sense of what it's doing when they read it. Knowledge of Python's approaches and mindset help me do that, even when Python language features are unavailable in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about single responsibility principle. It's not going to help you make a good decision here because you can subjectively choose a particular concept as a "responsibility." You could say the class' responsibility is managing data persistence to the database, or you could say its responsibility is to perform all the work related to creating a user. These are just different levels of the application's behavior, and they're both valid conceptual expressions of a "single responsibility." So this principle is unhelpful for solving your problem.

The most useful principle to apply in this case is [the principle of least surprise](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/1f9df7/the_only_valid_measurement_of_code_quality/). So let's ask the question: is it *surprising* that a repository with the primary role of persisting data to a database also sends e-mails?

**Yes,** it very much is surprising. These are two completely separate external systems, and the name `SaveChanges` does not imply also sending notifications. The fact you delegate this out to an event makes the behavior even more surprising, since someone reading the code can no longer easily see what additional behaviors are invoked. Indirection harms readability. Sometimes, the benefits are worth the readability costs, but not when you're automatically invoking an additional external system that has effects observable to end users. (Logging can be excluded here since its effect is essentially record keeping for debugging purposes. End users do not consume the log, so there is no harm in always logging.) Even worse, this reduces flexibility in the *timing* of sending the e-mail, making it impossible to interleave other operations between the save and the notification.

If your code typically needs to send a notification when a user is successfully created, you could create a method that does so:

```cs
public void AddUserAndNotify(IUserRepository repo, IEmailNotification notifier, MyUser user)
{
    repo.Add(user);
    repo.SaveChanges();
    notifier.SendUserCreatedNotification(user);
}
```

But whether this adds value depends on your application's specifics.

---

I'd actually discourage the existence of the `SaveChanges` method at all. This method will presumably commit a database transaction, but **other repositories might have modified the database in the same transaction**. The fact it commits all of them is again surprising, since `SaveChanges` is specifically tied to this instance of the user repository.

The most straightforward pattern for managing a database transaction is an outer `using` block:

```cs
using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
{
    _userRepository.Add(context, user);
    context.SaveChanges();
    notifier.SendUserCreatedNotification(user);
}
```

This gives the programmer explicit control over when changes for *all* repositories are saved, forces the code to explicitly document the sequence of events that must occur before a commit, ensures a rollback is issued on error (assuming that `DataContext.Dispose` issues a rollback), and avoids hidden connections between stateful classes.

I'd also prefer not to send the e-mail directly in the request. It would be more robust to record the *need* for a notification in a queue. This would allow for better failure handling. In particular, if an error occurs sending the e-mail, it can be tried again later without interrupting saving the user, and it avoids the case where the user is created but an error is returned by the site.

```cs
using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
{
    _userRepository.Add(context, user);
    _emailNotificationQueue.AddUserCreateNotification(user);
    _emailNotificationQueue.Commit();
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It's better to commit the notification queue first since the queue's consumer can verify that the user exists before sending the e-mail, in the event that the `context.SaveChanges()` call fails. (Otherwise, you'll need a full-blown two-phase commit strategy to avoid heisenbugs.)

---

The bottom line is to be practical. Actually think through the consequences (both in terms of risk and benefit) of writing code a particular way. I find that "single responsibility principle" doesn't very often help me do that, while "principle of least surprise" often helps me get into another developer's head (so to speak) and think about what might happen.

Comment: _is it surprising that a repository with the primary role of persisting data to a database also sends e-mails_ - I think you missed the point of my question. My repository is not sending emails. It just raises an event, and how this event is handled - is the responsibility of external code.

Comment: @AndreBorges My answer says, "The fact you delegate this out to an event makes the behavior even more surprising, since someone reading the code can no longer easily see what additional behaviors are invoked. Indirection harms readability." You're still thinking in terms of SRP. The whole point of my answer is that thinking that way is not helping you write better code. Good code makes most of what someone else needs to know about it *obvious* when they read it, and the way you've structured your code does not do so.

Comment: You're basically making the argument "don't use events."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yup. They make the connections between different parts of code much harder to discover, which makes understanding the sequence of events that occurs a much more difficult task. As I said, sometimes it's worth that price, but it's definitely a price you want to avoid paying whenever you can (which is usually in my experience).

Comment: *[shrug]* Events are central to most UI frameworks.  Eliminate events, and those frameworks don't work at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Which is part of why UI frameworks are really hard to work with and very easy to get wrong. ;) In a web context (which is what databases are typically used for), they're nearly never necessary or even useful, since the web backend really can't trigger events you might need to have your code respond to on demand. Receiving a request is the only event that happens.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have also sometimes wondered if UI frameworks could be restructured to mirror the relationship between a web page and a web framework. You could have a front end that sends requests to a back end that routes them to the appropriate code, ensuring that each event is handled in a stateless manner and on a separate thread from the UI. Seems like it would be easier, but maybe there's something I'm not thinking of. Maybe it would perform worse?

Comment: @jpmc26: It's called ASP.NET Webforms.  It sucks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Webforms is a *web* technology... not a desktop one. I'm talking about something more like using straight up HTML/CSS/JS for your UI and then having backend code written using a web framework. Not *exactly*, but something similar to that in principle.

Comment: Webforms is a web technology masquerading as a desktop technology. It uses the kind of event structure you described.

Comment: @RobertHarvey *thinks* Actually, I take it back. I'm not arguing against events. What I'm arguing against in this answer is indirection that is unnecessary. All events do in this case is get your code out of sequence. The repository is not waiting for something to happen; it's performing an operation on request. Events should be limited to triggering behavior that occurs at a time under the control of an external source (such as a user). A web request handler is essentially sequential: once the request is received, perform operations in order until a response is generated and returned.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As for ASP.NET Webform, no, I don't think so. What I'm thinking about is more like a single page web app. The user interacts with the front end, the front end then sends commands to the back end, the back end performs them and sends back a response, and then the front end modifies its state based on the response. ASP.NET Webforms seems to be trying to give more control to the back end, instead of making it under the complete control of the front end.

Comment: `My repository is not sending emails. It just raises an event` cause-effect. The repository is triggering the notification process.

Answer (score 1):

**No** this does not violate the SRP.

Many seem to think the Single Responsibility Principle means a function should only do "one thing", and then get caught up in discussion about what constitute "one thing".

But that is not what the principle means. It is about business-level concerns. A class should not implement multiple concerns or requirements which may change independently at the business level. Lets say a class both stores the user and sends a hardcoded welcome message via email. Multiple *independent* concerns could cause the requirements of such a class to change. The designer could require the html/stylesheet of the mail to change. The communications expert could require the wording of the mail to change. And the UX expert could decide the mail should actually be sent at a different point in the onboarding flow. So the class is subject to multiple requirement changes from independent sources. This violates the SRP.

But firing an event does not violate the SRP then, since the event only depends on saving the user and not on any other concern. Events are actually a really nice way to uphold the SRP, since you can have en email triggered by the save without the repository being affected by - or even knowing about - the mail.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `SaveChanges` does **two** things: it saves the changes **and** logs that it does so. Now you want to add another thing to it: send email notifications.

You had the clever idea to add an event to it, but this was criticised for violating the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP), without noticing that it had already been violated.

To get a pure SRP solution, *first* trigger the event, *then* call all the hooks for that event, of which there are now three: saving, logging, and finally sending emails.

Either you trigger the event first, or you have to add to `SaveChanges`. Your solution is a hybrid between the two. It doesn't address the existing violation while it does encourage preventing it from increasing beyond three things. Refactoring the existing code to comply with SRP might require more work than is strictly necessary. It's up to your project how far they want to take SRP.

Answer (score -1):

The code already violated the SRP -- the same class was responsible for communicating with the data context and logging.

You just upgrade it to having 3 responsibilities.

One way to strip things back to 1 responsibility would be to abstract the `_userRepository`; make it a command-broadcaster.

It has a set of commands, plus a set of listeners.  It gets commands, and broadcasts them to its listeners.  Possibly those listeners are ordered, and maybe they can even say the command failed (which in turn is broadcast to listeners who had already been notified).

Now, most of the commands may have only 1 listener (the data context).  SaveChanges, prior to your changes, has 2 -- the data context, and then the logger.

Your change then adds another listener to save changes, which is to raise new user created events in the event service.

There are a few benefits to this.  You can now remove, upgrade, or replicate the logging code without the rest of your code caring.  You can add more triggers at the save changes for more things that need it.

All of this gets decided when the `_userRepository` is created and wired up (or, maybe, those extra features get added/removed on the fly; being able to add/enhance logging while the application runs could be of use).